# Different version of C# used in some DLL-s of the solution

Tags: c#, c#-7.0, c#-7.1

I have got a solution consisting of 10+ projects. I am mainly responsible for one of these projects, which is basically a DLL, being called by other subparts of the solution. I would find it better to change the C# version from 7.0 to 7.1 - or to the latest - for some reasons.

I have got two questions:

- Can the different versions of certain sub-projects cause any trouble
  in the future?
- Do you consider changing C# version to the latest a good practice?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: After compiling, `c#` versions don't matter.

Comment: `Do you consider changing C# version to the latest a good practice?` As a general rule, yes.

Comment: As a general rule: The newest stable release of something is likely to be better than an older release, this is the same with language versions. And as SᴇM pointed out, after compiling the code it doesn't matter. Also Microsoft (and .NET) is insanely focused on backwards compatibility, so anything working in C# 7.0 is basically guaranteed to work in C# 7.1, C# 8.0 and most likely more that are to be released in the future

Comment: If the last version of C# stable just install it, before you upgrade commit your code than maybe use other branch with newest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes for incremental version updates should not be much of an issue.
If you use a source control system, which you should, then it will be relatively trivial.

create a separate branch, change the version of all projects.

if you use TFS, if I remember correctly, as I haven't touched that in many years, you simply check out the files and if anything goes wrong, you undo the edit actions.